# Rails Factory Girl "Create" not saving record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, factory-bot

I have two capybara tests that are testing the signup process on my rails application, both using factory girl.  One is just using Factory Girl build command and saving it with the form:

```
  it 'should create a user and associated customer_info', js: true do
    visit signup_path
    user = build(:user)
    customer = build(:customer_info)

    sign_up user, customer
    page.should have_content 'Welcome back, ' + customer.firstname
  end
```

Whereas the other is using the create command, and then attempting to sign in with that info.

```
  it 'should be able to sign in', js: true do
    user = create(:user)
    customer = create(:customer_info, user_id: user.id)

    visit new_user_session_path
    fill_in 'user_email', with: user.email
    fill_in 'user_password', with: user.password
    click_button 'Sign in'
    page.should have_content 'Welcome back, ' + customer.firstname
  end
```

The first one passes and saves in my test database.  The second one fails, saying "invalid email or password," but also when I check my database after each test, the first one saves a record but the second one doesn't (which I'm assuming is why it's saying invalid email/password).

Any ideas why my FactoryGirl create function isn't actually saving my record in the database?

**EDIT**

I have a sequence in my FactoryGirl definition for the email, and build AND create both increase the sequence, so it shouldn't be creating dups, right?

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "foo#{n}@example.com"}
    password "secret"
    password_confirmation "secret"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are trying to create duplicate user. Sign up creates user in test database and now when you are trying to create a new user with FactoryGirl it would raise validation error because the same user is already there in test database. You should do something like this:

```
def create_user
  @user ||= create(:user)
end

it 'should create a user and associated customer_info', js: true do
    visit signup_path
    @user = build(:user)
    customer = build(:customer_info)

    sign_up @user, customer
    page.should have_content 'Welcome, ' + customer.firstname
end

it 'should be able to sign in', js: true do
    create_user
    customer = create(:customer_info, user_id: @user.id)

    visit new_user_session_path
    fill_in 'user_email', with: @user.email
    fill_in 'user_password', with: @user.password
    click_button 'Sign in'
    page.should have_content 'Welcome back, ' + customer.firstname
end
```

May be you can use the different approach to solve it. but main focus is on to use the single user object for sign up and sign in.
Hope this would help you.

Comment: See my edit.  it shouldn't make a difference if I have a sequence, right?

Comment: can you puts user in both the scenario and make sure what the email assigned ?

Comment: yes, I had that and it was assigning user.email foo1@example.com.  Also, when I run that specific test by itself it still doesn't run.

Comment: Even with the sequence you'll run into uniqueness validation errors. By using `create`, you're saving foo1@example.com to the database. Then, via Capybara, you're entering the email for :user (`foo1@example.com) and trying to save again. It's not like your call to user.email is generating a new email address. Does that make sense?

Comment: Right, that makes sense.  I use database cleaner, and I have before each cleaner.start, and after each cleaner.clean.  Does that run after each test?

Comment: Actually, that still doesn't make sense to me.  If there is a sequence, with `build` it should be foo1@example.com, and it uses that to create a user.  And with `create`, it should be foo2@example.com, right?

Comment: @jake. yes exactly. So I was confirming it by puts the email in both the scenario.